# Minimum number of transpositions to sort a list

Tags: ds.algorithms, co.combinatorics, sorting

In trying to devise my own sorting algorithm, I'm looking for the optimal benchmark to which I can compare it.  For an unsorted ordering of elements *A* and a sorted ordering *B*, what is an efficient way to calculate the optimal number of transpositions to get from *A* to *B* ?

A transposition is defined as switching the position of 2 elements in the list, so for instance

```
1 2 4 3
```

has one transposition (transposition 4 and 3) to make it

```
1 2 3 4
```

Something like

```
1 7 2 5 9 6
```

requires 4 transpositions (7, 2), (7, 6), (6,5), (9, 7)

Update (9/7/11): question changed to use "transposition" instead of "swaps" to refer to non-adjacent exchanges.

Comment: what if you can just swap neighbors?
how can I figure out the minimum number of swaps?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're only dealing with permutations of $n$ elements, then you will need exactly $n-c(\pi)$ swaps, where $c(\pi)$ is the number of cycles in the [disjoint cycle decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_notation) of $\pi$. Since this distance is bi-invariant, transforming $\pi$ into $\sigma$ (or $A$ into $B$, or conversely) requires $n-c(\sigma^{-1}\circ\pi)$ such moves.

Comment: Despite voting for this a long time ago, it just clicked today.  Like a Rubik's cube, right :D?

Answer (score 12):

The swap distance can also be isometrically embedded in Euclidean space. For each string s, construct a matrix $M(s)$ where $M_{ij} = 1$ if $i$ occurs before $j$ and is zero otherwise. Then the Frobenius distance $\|M(s) - M(s')\|^2$ is the swap distance $d(s,s')$. (from [Graham Cormode's slides](http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/~graham/pubs/slides/dmsa.pdf)). Not as elegant as Anthony's answer, but quite easy to compute.

Update: please see Oleksandr's comments

Comment: It seems to me that in Graham's presentation they mean spectral norm ($\|A\|_2$) and not Frobenius norm ($\|A\|_F$).

Comment: although if all you want to do is count the differences, then the square of the frobenius norm should work right ?

Comment: which is of course the Hamming distance for 0-1 matrices

Comment: You're right about equality between the square of Frobenius norm and Hamming distance. I'd like to add that Hamming distance divided by $2$ equals swap distance. But the question was about transposition distance ("A swap is defined as switching the position of 2 elements in the list") and not about swap distance. What concerns spectral norm it is the square of it equals to swap distance.

Comment: Oleksandr: So I suppose that you interpret "swapping" as "exchanging two adjacent elements"?

Comment: @Anthony Labarre: Yes. But the author of the question seems to use swapping for transposition. (This is seen especially from his second example.)

Comment: I think Oleksandr is right here. I'll edit the answer

Comment: @Suresh Venkat Although this question is a bit older, don't you think it would be prudent to change the question to use "transposition" in place of "swap"?