# Efficient recognition of sequences sortable by transpositions?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, sorting

While reading the post, [*Probability of generating a desired permutation by random swaps*, by Aaronson](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/25427/probability-of-generating-a-desired-permutation-by-random-swaps), I got interested in restricted sorting problem:

If we restrict sorting algorithms to use transpositions (swapping integers in two non-adjacent positions) and restrict the number of transpositions then some sequences are sortable and others are not.

Note that sequence $A$ may contain some **repeated** integers

Formally, the problem is:

**Input**: a sequence $A=[a_1, a_2, ..., a_{2N}]$ of $2N$ positive (possibly repeated) integers.

**Question**: Is it possible to sort sequence $A$ using $N$ transpositions of non-adjacent positions?

> Is there a polynomial-time algorithm to solve this problem? Or Is it NP-complete?

This was post on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191539/recognizing-sequences-sortable-by-transpositions).

P.S. This problem has a nice geometric interpretation: It is equivalent to deciding the existence of a path of length at most N between two points on a special [2N-Permutahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutohedron).

Special permutahedron means that two nodes are connected by an edge if and only if the corresponding permutations are separated by one *non-adjacent* transposition.

[image: Permutahedron of order 4]

**Edit**: I am interested in the case where the input sequence $A$ is restricted to permutation of $[1,2,3, …, 2N]$. Is it efficiently solvable under this restriction?

Comment: By two non-adjacent elements, do you mean two elements which need not be adjacent? If that's what you mean, there's a polynomial-time algorithm for it. If you mean they must not be adjacent, I don't know the answer.

Comment: @PeterShor Let $a_i$ and $a_j$ two elements in $A$. There are non-adjacent if $|i-j| \gt 1$.

Comment: @PeterShor I mean that the two elements must not be adjacent in $A$ as shown above.

Comment: @PeterShor : $\:$ I thought that was only known for the case in which the elements are all distinct. $\;\;$

Comment: If we allowed adjacent transpositions, we'd need exactly $2N-c(\pi)$ transpositions to express $\pi$, where $c(\pi)$ is the number of cycles in the cycle decomposition of $\pi$ (see http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/4096/5038).  Given a cycle $\sigma=(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k)$, let its badness $b(\sigma)$ be the number of pairs $(a_1,a_2)$, $(a_2,a_3)$, ..., $(a_{k-1},a_k)$, $(a_k,a_1)$ that are adjacent.  Let $b'(\pi)$ be the number of cycles in the cycle decomposition of $\pi$ whose badness is $\ge 2$.  Then you need at least $2N-c(\pi)+b'(\pi)$ non-adjacent transpositions to express $\pi$.

Comment: @D.W. Thanks for the link. I am just interested in the complexity of the problem :)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but seems potentially related: inversion-(nearly)-optimal sorting by [Elmasry & Fredman](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00236-007-0061-0)

Comment: It can be solved using one of these two methods ... 1-Characteristic polynomial
2- Horner's method